# Install specific gem utility

Tags: ruby

I have two machines, both have the same Ruby version.

But the version of the `gem` utility is different.

How can I install the correct version of the `gem`
utility? Google tells me how to install gems, but not how to install the utility itself.

So far, the only way I see is to copy-paste the correct `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem` file from one machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague found the solution

`gem update --system <version-number>`

This command successfully downgraded the utility's version.